# Simplest MySql query uses filesort and ignores created_at index?

Tags: mysql, index, performance, optimization, query-performance

I have the simplest possible MySql query and am confused about why it's using filesort instead of relying on my index.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT 
    id,
    created_at
FROM
    contacts
ORDER BY created_at DESC;
```

This result shows that it uses the index:

```
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+---------------------------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key                       | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+---------------------------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | contacts | NULL       | index | NULL          | contacts_created_at_index | 5       | NULL |  377 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+---------------------------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
```

But then look at this next query (the same but now also has `emailAddress`):

```
EXPLAIN SELECT 
    id,
    created_at,
    emailAddress
FROM
    contacts
ORDER BY created_at DESC;
```

Why does its result say "Using Filesort"?

```
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table    | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra          |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | contacts | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |  377 |   100.00 | Using filesort |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------+
```

I've already read [ORDER BY Optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html) and [Index Hints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html) from the MySQL documentation.

Adding the hint `USE INDEX FOR ORDER BY(contacts_created_at_index)` doesn't help.

My table has many more columns than these. The `id` is primary key, and `created_at` has a basic index, and `emailAddress` has a unique index, and there are other columns.

I'm using this table in Laravel 5.4.

Comment: So, do you need all the rows of the table returned? If the table has a million rows? If it has 100 millions?

Comment: In other words, now that the table has a tiny 400 rows, why do you care what index is used? I would bet it's fast anyway. And sorting 400 rows can't be a problem.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ It will never have millions of rows. Only a few thousand. And it's already slower than I'd have guessed: 0.844 sec. It should definitely be faster.

Comment: @Ryan how much faster should it be?

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik I'm not very familiar with how fast queries should be, but I could have sworn the MySql databases I've worked on always returned simple queries in ~0.1 sec or less.  I wonder if this Cloudways server I'm now using is somehow less capable / slower than I'm used to.

Comment: If ID is an auto increment integer. I typically suggest you order by id instead of create date. It's already a primary key index, accomplishes the same thing...

Answer (score 1):

- With InnoDB, any secondary index (such as `INDEX(created_id)`) implicitly includes a copy of the `PRIMARY KEY` (`id`).  Hence, the first query is "covering" as indicated by "Using index".
- When you need to look at more than about 20% of a table, it is actually faster to ignore the index, and do a full table scan -- rather than bouncing between the index and the data.  (The index and the data are separate BTree structures, connected by that PK copy.)
- `ORDER BY` causes a filesort unless it can be consumed by the index it is using.  (But it is not using it, as the above point points out.)
- MySQL rarely uses more than one index in a `SELECT`.  (Because using multiple indexes would be more complex, and almost always slower.)

That is just a few of the possible things that can go on (other than the items I just mentioned).

See also [*my Index Cookbook*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/building-the-best-index-for-a-given-select/) .